# Is $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{l\cdot n}\frac{f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}{n}$ a valid definite integral riemann sum? What is it called if so?

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

I came up with this alternate Riemann sum that correctly gives the value of a definite integral (at least for some simple polynomial and trig functions I tested with wolfram alpha):

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{l\cdot n}\frac{f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}{n}$$

where $l$ is the value we want from the antiderivative.

That is,

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{l\cdot n}\frac{f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}{n} = \int_{0}^l f(x)$$

Here is the "classic" version from Calculus textbooks I've seen:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

And here is my version on some interval $[a,b]$ instead of $[0,l]$:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\left(b-a\right)\cdot n}\frac{f\left(a+\frac{i}{n}\right)}{n}$$

I tried looking for more information on it with no success. I want to know is it valid in all cases, is it really somehow just a trivial rewrite of the classic version and does it have a name? Is there some textbook or other resource that mentions it somewhere or somewhere to learn more about it? To me I see it as very different from the "average value" that the classic Riemann sum does, although I think you can still view it that way. Sorry if this is a trivial rewrite of the other version, I am new to calculus.

I like this version better because it is more easy to understand in my opinion because to me it shows the "reversal" of the derivative definition more clearly:

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

It is more clear to me in the version I proposed that multiplying by $\frac{1}{n}$ in the Riemann sum is canceling out the $h$ from the derivative. And then we are just adding up all the original values of $f$ that $f'$ is derived from. As opposed to the classic version where we multiply by $\frac{b-a}{n}$

Comment: If $l$ is not an integer, how do you define $\sum_{i=1}^{l\cdot n}$? For example, what does $\sum_{i=1}^{3.2}$ mean?

Comment: @Kaira wow that's a great point which I didn't think of. I guess you could shift everything over by 1/10 so it would be sum from 1 to 32, then just divide by 10n instead n in the function. FWIW wolfram alpha accepts 3.2 in the sum and seems to give the right answer for the definite integral of x^4 at 3.2 Here it is: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BSum%5BDivide%5B4Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2Cn%5D%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bi%2C1%2C3.2n%7D%5D%2Cn-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D

Comment: I think the same trick does not work if you have irrational numbers e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^{\pi}$. I don't know why W|A can output "correct" values, but it probably evaluates the sum symbolically and then substitutes specific values.

Comment: @Kaira It does seem to work for some irrational numbers. I tried sqrt(2), e and pi. You can see it here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BSum%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bsin%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2Cn%5D%5C%2841%29%2C3%5D%2Cn%5D%2C%7Bi%2C1%2CeSqrt%5B2%5Dn%7D%5D%2Cn-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D . In the step by step solution it always simplifies the sum into a closed form (removing the sum) before doing anything though. So I don't know how/if it would solve it if there was no closed form. Even if such a case exits (I'm sure it does), does that necessarily invalidate the notation in those cases?

Comment: What W|A seems to be doing is to "define" the expression $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{l\cdot n}f(i/n)/n$ to be the integral $\int_{0}^{l}f(x)dx$, so it feels like a "cheating" to me. In this case, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{l\cdot n}f(i/n)/n$ is indeed equal to the integral, but we defined it to be so.

Comment: It is valid (as long as the sum runs over the integers $i$ between $1$ and $l\cdot n$), but it seems a rather trivial rewrite of the other version to me as you pointed out. In fact, sticking to one of the either versions sounds too restrictive for practical applications. Later you may possibly learn a much general version of the Riemann integral that has greater flexibility.

Comment: For the record, here is a screenshot of how it gets the answer for an irrational case: https://imgur.com/GNQu5Gz. I do not know enough to say if it is defining $limn→∞∑l⋅ni=1f(i/n)/n  := ∫l0f(x)dx$. It does not appear that way to me as it evaluates the sum on it's own and only solves the limit after.

Comment: Ok, I take the earlier comment back; it seems what we were getting at earlier is correct. They evaluate the sum first and substitute $ln$ later. As you pointed out earlier, this wouldn't work if there is no closed-form formula, and as the other commenter pointed out, this can be corrected if you interpret the sum as $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor ln \rfloor}$ $\lfloor ln \rfloor$ is the largest integer below $ln$.

Comment: I would say this is a simplification of the standard Riemann sum form of an integral.  In some contexts this will be an over-simplification.  For many of the sums done in Calculus I, this will be valid.  However, if you go further onto real analysis, it would be helpful to already have a full understanding of the Calculus I definition of a Riemann sum.
One difference likely to have an effect- these are when using the right endpoint of each subinterval to calculate the height.  Left endpoint or mid point will require slight adjustments.